Variational calculus with constraints of boundary conditions. How to take into account
I am looking for references to understand the following.
I've recently solved the thin plate functional minimization subjected to interpolation constraints.
The calculations I did are mostly here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/447261/thin-plate-spline-understanding-and-solution
What I recently added on top was some constraints for the boundary conditions. Something like
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\int_{\Omega} \left(f_{xx}^2 + 2f_{xy}^2 + f_{yy}^2\right)dxdy \\
\text{s.t.} \\ 
f(x_i,y_i) = z_i & i=1,\ldots,n \\
f(x,y) = g(x,y) & (x,y) \in \partial \Omega
\end{array}
\right.
$$
My assumption in this case is that I could somewhat use the Lagrange multipliers for this problem as well, as I did for the interpolation condition. However I don't know why I get stuck when attempting. The closest thing I could come up was encoding the constraint as a line integral but I don't think this is correct.
Other attempt was to derive the Euler Lagrange equations by keeping in mind my boundary constraint during the integration by parts (which I think is the same as the line integral I mentioned earlier).
However I still think I am doing something wrong.
Last idea is remembering what I did in my other post which gave me a PDE of the form
$$
\Delta^2 f = -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i \omega_i
$$
Maybe in this case can the equivalent PDE of my new problem can be written simply as
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\Delta^2 f = -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i \omega_i & (x,y) \in \text{ Interior } \Omega \\
f = g & (x,y) \in \partial \Omega
\end{array}
\right.
$$
I still wonder however if this can come from the cost function above
Can anybody give me a reference or some suggestions?
